# Python is soft link to python2.7, how to change link to python 3

Tags: 14.04, python3

on Ubuntu 14.04 has python-3, python-2.7 and python is linked to python-2.7 by default. I have to run python-3 code on ubuntu -14.04. Can I modify /usr/bin/python link to python3? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: check `sudo update-alternatives --list python`  If multiple versions are listed, you cen set which one to use with `sudo update-alternatives --set python`

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --list python                                                    tried above command showing no alternatives with below error:                                       update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python

Answer (score 7):

Don't do that.

A lot of things will (probably) break if you change the default python interpreter to python3.

The switch is not a simple one --- although by 16.04 I think that all the system scripts will be python3, it will probably not switched even then (thanks @florian-deisch). Other distros, like Arch, [did the switch](https://www.archlinux.org/news/python-is-now-python-3/), but I am not sure if this is a good thing, given that [there is a PEP explicitly suggesting the contrary](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)...

Simply use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

as the "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)" line (first line) of the scripts that you want to be run by python3.

Comment: Most likely `/usr/bin/python` will still not point to python3 in 16.04 as recommended by [PEP 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Indeed. `for the time being, all distributions should ensure that python refers to the same target as python2 .`

Comment: The PEP came about *because* Arch made Python 3 the default.

Comment: I can not make virtual environment as my scripts are running on Embedded / target board,which has Ubuntu 14.04 with minimal package support. As I'm running my application on embedded board, i have memory constraint. So i can not install many packages, which may lead to insufficient memory problem. Any other idea / way?

Comment: Any other way so that i can point python to python-3. I have ported my application to python-3. Will it run with both python-2 and python-3? How to isolate python-2 dependencies and make sure it is running only on python-3? Please do share your views. I'm Stuck..!!